# Spark Check if there is At Least n element in dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I am using Spark (2.3.1) to do some processing on datasets. For some reason, I would like to know if there is enough data in my Dataset before doing my computation.

The basic solution to do that is the following :

```
int count = myDataset.count();
int threshold = 100;

if (count>threshold){
    // compute
}else{
    System.out.println("Not enough data to do computation");
}
```

But it is really inefficient. Another solution that is a bit more efficient is to use the countApprox() function.

```
int count = (long) (myDataset.rdd().countApprox(1000,0.90).getFinalValue().mean());
```

But in my case, it could be way more efficient.

What is the best way to solve this problem ?

Note :

- I was thinking iterating over my data, manualy counting my rows and stopping when I reach the threshold, but I am not sure it is the best solution.

Comment: What is the source of your data?

Comment: @nakeuh can you check the answer and see if it works for you?

Comment: What are the odds that data is smaller than threshold? How the subsequent process look like? How `myDataset` is created?

Comment: The chances of data being smaller than the threshold are small but not negligible. `myDataset` is a dataset read from a database with few mapping (extract day of week from timestamp, normalize column name, filter some rows etc...). I then use this dataset to feed some Machine Learning algorithms (MLLIB or else), and I want to generate my ML models only if I have enough input data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `myDataset.count()`, it will scan full data and might be slow.

To speed this up, you can do a `limit(threshold+1)` on your dataset. This will return you another dataset with `threshold+1` rows. On this, you can do `.count()`.

```
    int threshold = 100;
    int totalRowsAfterLimit = myDataset.limit(threshold+1).count();

    if (totalRowsAfterLimit > threshold) {
        // compute
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not enough data to do computation");
    }
```

`limit(threshold+1)` will make sure that your underlying job only reads limited number of records and it will finish faster.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, "limit" can be more efficient:

```
df.limit(threshold).count()
```